# How can I get the class object, when I only know the classname at runtime

Tags: objective-c, class, runtime

I need to get the class object out of a string, containing the name of the class at runtime. I found a function called objc_getClass, but I'm not sure if it's really what I search.

Can I implement it like this?
NSString *name = @"AnyClass";
Class *myClass = objc_getClass([name UTF8String]);

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe the function you're looking for is:

```
NSClassFromString(@"AnyClass");
```

which lets you do:

```
id obj = [[NSClassFromString(@"AnyClass") alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer myself ^^NSClassFromString is my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't mean:

AnyClass *myClassInstance = [[AnyClass alloc] init];

Or has this class been instantiated and you need a pointer to it? You might need to give more details.

Comment: No i read the class name from a file and i want to instantiate it at runtime.